# AWK: select rows from shell variables

Tags: shell, variables, awk, subset

Here I have two files data.txt and mrk.txt.

in 1st line I want to select id that marked with 2 in the 2nd column. and 2nd line I want to just keep rows starting with those ids (3,5,8,9,10) and delete the rest. Does anyone knows how can I make it?

```
dam=$(awk '$2==2 {print $1}' data.txt)
./QmSim2uga.awk -v genotyped="$dam" mrk.txt > c_mark_001
```

QMSim2uga.awk is

```
#!/bin/gawk -f
BEGIN{
nind=0
FIELDWIDTHS = "3 1 1 1 1 1"
}
($1 == dam){        
    nsnp=NF-1
    genotype=""
    for (i=1; i<=nsnp; i++){
        out=$(i+1)
        # QmSim -> UGA
        # 0 -> AA -> 0
        # 2 -> aa -> 2
        # 3 -> Aa -> 1
        # 4 -> aA -> 1
        # (missing does not exist) -> 5
        if(out>2) {out=1} 
        genotype=genotype out
    }
    if (NR % 10000 ==0){ printf("%s\n",NR) > "/dev/stderr" }
    printf("%10s%1s%" nsnp "s\n",$1," ",genotype)
    nind++
}
END{
printf("%s%10s%10s\n","nsnp, nanim",nsnp,NR) > "/dev/stderr"
}
```

data.txt

> ```
> 1  1
> 2  1
> 3  2
> 4  1
> 5  2
> 6  1
> 7  1
> 8  2
> 9  2
> 10 2
> ```

mrk.txt

> ```
> 1  02340
> 2  20433
> 3  43220
> 4  32344
> 5  02233
> 6  30423
> 7  24430
> 8  00223
> 9  03342
> 10 34402
> ```

the desired ouput will be, "3" and "4" in 2nd column of mrk.txt file should be replaced with 1

> ```
> 3  11220
> 5  02211
> 8  00221
> 9  01112
> 10 11102
> ```

But right now with the code given, the ouptfile is empty

Comment: What's your current and desired output, and what's wrong with the code you have now?

Comment: The desired ouput is 3 43220(/n) 5 02333(/n) and so on, right now the output file is empty. I don't know what is wrong here.

Comment: OK so that's about one third of my question answered.

Comment: Do you have an idea for modifying the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the new requirement

old requirement

```
awk 'x[$1];{x[$1]=$2~2}' file file
```

new requirement

```
awk 'a[$1]{gsub(/(3|4)/,"1",$2);print}{a[$1]=$2~2}' file file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
join data.txt mrk.txt | awk '$2 == 2 { print $1, $3 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below awk script:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    cnt=0
}
NR == FNR{
    if ($2 == 2)
       arr[cnt++] = $1
}
NR != FNR{
    for(i=0; i<cnt; i++)
        if(arr[i] == $1)
           print $0
}' data.txt mrk.txt
```

In the `NR==FNR` code block, if second field value is 2, we store the corresponding `$1` in `arr`.

In the `NR!=FNR` block (i.e `mrk.txt`), we check the `arr` and `$1`. If matches, the line is printed.

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler `awk` script can implement what you want.

```
awk '$2==2{a[FNR]=$1} FNR!=NR && $1 in a{print $0}' data.txt mrk.txt
```

will produce

```
3  43220
5  02233
8  00223
9  03342
10 34402
```

What it does?

`$2==2{a[FNR]=$1}` selects all rows where `$2==2` and save the `$1` in array `a`

`FNR!=NR` will select the second file `mrk.txt`

`$1 in a` checks if column 1,`$1` is in array `a` if yes prints the entire record  `{print $0}`

EDIT

To replace `3` and `4` with `1`

```
awk '$1 in a{gsub("[34]","1",$2); print $0};$2==2{a[FNR]}'
```

will produce output

```
3 11220
5 02211
8 00221
9 01112
10 11102
```

`gsub("[34]","1",$2)`

replaces every occurence of regular expression `[34]` with `1` in the second column `$2`

Comment: dont need the `print $0`, awk will print it if no brackets are opened after the argument.

Comment: @Jidder Agree with you. Thank you for pointing out. Just added for clarity.

Comment: Okay, also you don't need to set `a[FNR]=$1`.Just `a[FNR]` would suffice as you are not ever using the value inside.As line numbers cannot repeat the whole thing could be reduced to `'$1 in a;$2==2{a[FNR]}' data.txt mrk.txt`

Comment: thanks a lot. Actually I want to change the 3 and 4 to 1 for elements in the 2nd column of mrk.txt file. I made a mistake when editing the desired output file.

Comment: @Jidder better. `a[FNR]` was a new think for me. :)